# Unable to see similar apps of same category in google playstore

Tags: android, app-store, google-play

I published a chatting app 2 weeks earlier. I am able to see my app in playstore. But I am not able to see `Similar apps`  section at the bottom.

## Category: social

Example: Other apps are shown like:

[image]

My app is shown like:

[image]

Does download matters or I am missing something?

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually it takes time to be indexed fully and I believe the algorithm takes into account similar downloads by users that consume your application.

With only a few `downloads` the algorithm probably has little data to go on.